# Java toString error

Tags: java, class, methods, tostring, multidimensional-array

I'm trying write a class for this program and this class creates a board for which an object moves in. the Board is supposed to look like a box with "+" on the four corners and "-" going vertically and "|" going horizontally with an empty center:

```
+-----+
|     |
|     |
|     |
|     |
+-----+
```

I, on the other hand, get brackets going horzontally around the edges, and commas filling the middle, I do not know why:

```
[ , , , , ] 
[ , , , , ]
[ , , , , ] 
[ , , , , ] 
[ , , , , ]
```

My program is right, but I need help with my class.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Board {

    private char [][] theBoard;

    public Board() { 
        this(10, 25); 
    }


    public Board (int rows, int cols) {
        if (rows < 1 || rows>80) {
            rows = 1;
        }
        if (cols<1 || cols > 80) {
            cols = 1;
        }
        theBoard = new char [rows][cols];
        for (int row = 0; row < theBoard.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < theBoard[row].length; col++)
                theBoard[row][col] = ' ';
    }
    }

        public void clearBoard() {
        for (int row = 0; row < theBoard.length; row++ ) {
        for (int col = 0; col < theBoard[row].length; col++) {
      if (theBoard[row][col] < '0' || theBoard[row][col] > '9') {
      theBoard[row][col] = ' ';   
    }
    }
    }
    }

            public void setRowColumn(int row, int col, char character) {
           theBoard[row][col] = character;
        }

            public char getRowColumn(int row, int col) {
            return theBoard[row][col];
        }

        public String toString() {
    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char[] chars : theBoard) {
        strb.append(Arrays.toString(chars) + "\n");
    }
    return strb.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      Board aBoard, anotherBoard;

      System.out.println("Testing default Constructor\n");
      System.out.println("10 x 25 empty board:");

      aBoard = new Board();
      System.out.println(aBoard.toString());

      System.out.println();

      // And, do it again
      System.out.println("Testing default Constructor again\n");
      System.out.println("10 x 25 empty board:");

      anotherBoard = new Board();
      System.out.println(anotherBoard.toString());

   } // end of method main
} // end of class
```

Comment: ~Thank you Luchian for that correction

Comment: What was the error? Try to change the toString() method.

Comment: Yeah it has something to do with the toString method, but I can't seem to find it >.< It just prints the wrong characters, but I was sure I had it..

Comment: [,,,] i essentially get something like that rather than +--+

Comment: The only plus signs in your code are either addition/concatenation operators or increment operators.  Not a single string or character containing "+".  Why would you expect your output to contain any?

Comment: Its your toString method. The `strb.append(Arrays.toString(chars) + "\n");` is being used incorrectly. Try iterating over the chars arrays and append to your buffer.

Answer (score 2):

The default constructor fills the array with empty spaces: `' '`.

When you call the `Arrays.toString()` method, it prints an open bracket, followed the contents of the array (separated by commas), followed by a closed bracket.

For example, if you had an array:

```
i  a[i]
0   1
1   2
3   5
4   8
```

Calling `Arrays.toString(a)` prints out:

```
[1, 2, 5, 8]
```

As another example, if you had an array filled with empty spaces, you'd get:

```
[ ,  ,  ,  ,  , ]
```

(see the spaces?)

This is why you're receiving that output.

Comment: Interesting, no wonder! I know how to make what I need to through accessor methods, but I have no idea how to use toString methods for this.

Comment: You could avoid using the `Arrays.toString()` method altogether by looping through the array and adding each character in the array to a string.  At the end of each row, put a new line in the string.

Comment: alright I got,      public String toString() { 
        int i;
        String temp = new String (""); 

            
            String line = "";
            char topBottom = '-';
 int k;
int row2 = theBoard[0].length;
for ( k = 0 ; k < row2 ; k++ ){
line += topBottom;             }
System.out.println('+' + line + '+');

for (i=0; i<theBoard.length; i++) {
 temp += "|";

                for (int j=0; j<theBoard[0].length; j++) {
                    temp = temp + theBoard[i][j] + "|"; 
                }
            temp += "\n";
            }
 return line + "\n" + temp + "\n" + line;

Comment: Also, there is no code in the toString() method to add the border characters to the output.

Comment: I got that, and I got the shape a little better, but it's still a little out of place